# Having trouble formatting code to desired output

Tags: python, string.format

I'm trying to get the code to print in the below format, however nothing seems to work out. Can someone point out the mistake in the code or logic?

*Desired format:* `We have got only 3 oranges and only 1 apple`

*Code:*

```
excess = {"apple": 5, "orange": 6}
s = ""
for k, v in excess.items():
    n = 1
    if n == 0:
        s = "We have got only {} {} ".format(v, k)
    elif n > 1:
        s += "and {} {}".format(v, k)  
    n += 1
print(bill, s)
```

*Output*

```
We have only 6 orange
```

Comment: I question how you got the output "We have only 6 orange". First of all, `bill` is not defined in this code block and you are setting `n = 1` in each iteration of the loop. Therefore `n == 0` and `n > 1` are always going to be false so your block of code should return an empty string `s = ""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `n` outside of the loop, and replace `n>1` condition with `n>0` (or `else`)

```py
excess={"apple":5,"orange":6}
s=""
n=0

for k,v in excess.items():
    if n==0:
        s="We have got only {} {}".format(v,k)
    else:
        s+=" and {} {}".format(v,k)  
    n+=1
    
print(s)
# We have got only 5 apple and 6 orange
```